# Select latest record for each id spring jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
class Point{
    @EmbeddedId
    private PointIdentity pointIdentity;
    private float latitude;
    private float longitude;

    @Embeddable
    public static class PointIdentity implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
        private ZonedDateTime timestamp;
    }
}
```

There is EmbeddedId, so in "id" column can be multiple records with the same ids.

And I need to get latest record for each id, using CriteriaQuery and JPA specifications I think, but don't know how.

In SQL, this would be something like this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(timestamp) 
FROM geodata 
GROUP BY id
```

Is there any way to do it?

Any help, thanks.

Comment: You mentioned there is an id, but you didn’t tell us what fields are part of it.

Comment: There is only one timestamp for each id (in the same row). It is unclear what your groups are (what do you mean by last record for each id)

Comment: @Lesiak I mean just the latest record for each id

Comment: Id, by definition, is unique. You cannot have multiple records with the same id.

Comment: @Lesiak, there is constraint key, sorry, id+timestamp, updated the code. So here can be multiple rows with the same id. maybe SQL query will make my question clear. I need to do this, only using spring jpa: SELECT id, MAX(timestamp) FROM geodata GROUP BY id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write a JPQL query:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select p.pointIdentity.id, max(p.pointIdentity.timestamp) from Point p group by p.pointIdentity.id",
    Object[].class);
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

which translates to:

```
select
    point0_.id as col_0_0_,
    max(point0_.timestamp) as col_1_0_ 
from
    point point0_ 
group by
    point0_.id
```

Alternatively, you can use criteria query:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Point> point = query.from(Point.class);
query.groupBy(point.get("pointIdentity").get("id"));
query.multiselect(
        point.get("pointIdentity").get("id"),
        criteriaBuilder.max(point.get("pointIdentity").get("timestamp"))
);
TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
List<Object[]> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

which produces identical SQL.